# Get Wordpress Category Slug

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I was wondering if there is any Wordpress function out there which returns the slug of a category by passing it's name. 
Something like:

http://blog.com/categoryName/slug

Or anything like that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This retrieves category object by category slug. It returns false if not found.

```
<?php get_category_by_slug( $slug ) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i was actually asking if it's possible to get the slug of a category by the name of the category.

Comment: I'm confused. Can you give me an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am looking for a method, where i can pass the category's name and receive the category's slug. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php 
    $slug = get_term_by("name", "tsss", "category"); 
    echo $slug->slug;
?>
```

where "category" is the name of the category.